# Blazor server side role or claim based authorization when using windows login

Tags: authorization, blazor, server-side

I am new to working with Blazor and Authorization.  Background is desktop apps in Vb.Net, so I have been reading everything I can on it, but it still is very confusing when I only want a specific subset of the options out there.

I have a very simple intranet Razor Server based app that is getting the windows user name correctly with default authentication.  (I use the name in calls to stored procedures for logging, so I know that is working correctly.)

What I need is to implement authorization (role based would be fine) based on information I have already in the database tied to the user name).
Where and how does one add roles to an existing authstatetask or other object instantiated by the default processes?
Everything I have seen deals with the EF version of Identity or wants to override the authorization task.
I have Simple DB calls being made in Dapper which will return an identifier from which I can set roles.
I just need pointers to the proper method and where in the app I should put it.  I have just a single .razor page being loaded, Navbar is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can either :

- Implement Identity stores for Dapper following instruction in this blog : [ASP.NET CORE IDENTITY WITHOUT ENTITY FRAMEWORK](https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/)
- Use [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and create authorization handlers meeting your requirements

Comment: Still alphabet soup to me.  The examples are not clear.  In the Policy Based stuff, I have no idea where some things go, should I include them or are they simply there for reference (IAuthorizationService section for example.)   They muddy things up with passing a minimum age value.

Comment: Most things I have found expect you to use the IDENTITY structures or replace that with your own login.  Using WIndows Authentication user and adding roles/claims to that is what I am looking for.  I am not a C# or Web guru, I need things properly identified where they should be placed and more of a structure outline as to where they go.  Once I understand something, I can run with it,  At this point, I have not been able to see the forest through the trees!